# errors using default for switch statement c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

im trying to use default at the end of my switch statement and i keep getting errors! im getting frustrated please help

im very new to programming and its quite confusing lol

```
case "d":

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your option here:");
    Console.WriteLine("First number");
    double firstNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Second number:");
    double secondNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double sum = firstNum / secondNum;
    Console.WriteLine("Result:" + sum);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    Console.ReadKey();
    break;
}
default:

    else if (number == 2)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting the code");
        Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
    }

    else
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Wrong selection");
        Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to go to the main menu");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

```
Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  ConsoleApp50        69  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  ConsoleApp50        69  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  ConsoleApp50        98  Active
```

Answer (score 3):

When the code is that weird, sometimes the error messages don't make sense :)

A few problems I see:

1. At the end of your `case "d":` block, you have a `}` where there was no previous `{`. Unless there is code in your `case "d":` block that you're not showing us, then you can just delete that `}`.
2. In your `default:` block, you're starting with an `else if`, where there was no `if` before that. You can only use `else if` after an `if`. Unless there's code you're not showing us, then you can change the `else if` to just `if`.
3. There's no `}` at the end, to close the `else` block.
4. You still need a `break;` at the end of the `default:` block.

Comment: oh yea sorry there is more code its just quite long so thought i better not put the whole thing lol, its basically a calculator and its got options to access each calculation. thanks ill try some of that tho

Comment: Ok. Maybe the error messages are correct then. It depends. The "expected" error messages are just telling you that the compiler is expecting to see specific characters (`;` or `}`) in a specific place and it's not seeing it.

Comment: yea thats what im getting confused with i guess, im adding the {} and ; but its not making a difference or its making it worse somehow, its probably so obvious but its confusing the hell out of me lol...

Comment: Sometimes, especially when it's complaining about a missing `}`, you're actually missing one earlier in your code. For example, if you miss one for closing off a method, it will complain that you aren't closing your class. (because the one that you think is closing your class is actually closing your method)

Comment: i mean as far as i can see, i dont think i have but like i said i am very new to this lol so i will have to go over it a few more times to figure it out i guess, thanks tho!